# Windows Insider builds in final, released Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I've installed full, released Windows 10 Pro over my Insider Preview build 10240. I got option to keep my programs and data. It installed in less than 30 minutes and works as charm.

But to my surprise I still have "Get Insider builds" option in my Windows Update settings, advanced options.

I also have the option "Stop Insider builds". Should I activate it? What are the consequences? The system I have installed seems to be still some kind of evaluation version. I chose to wait and see what happens, but I'm just curious how this works.

Will there be any further Insider builds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Insider Preview is going to continue indefinitely.  The only reason you should have "Stop Insider Preview" is if you installed from either Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.1 Update 1 installation from a previous build of the Insider Preview.  You will have to decide if staying in the program, which will require to continue to install new builds as they are released, is something you want to deal with.

If you did upgrade from either Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 feel free to leave the program, you installation will remain activated indefinitely, you will be required to install updates after they have been sent to people who are in the Insider Preview though per the EULA.